# C# - Unable to create a constant value of type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this error

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Controllers.Administrator'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

I have a variable `List<Administrator> result` that is getting it's values from `Database.SqlQuery<Administrator>`.

Administrator class looks like this

```
public class Administrator
    {
        public string AdminName { get; set; }
        public string Numer { get; set; }
    }
```

Than I have something like this

```
var sheet = from k in Context.Admins.AsNoTracking()
            select new Admin()
            {
              // some other variables  
              Numer = k.Numer,           
              AdminName = result.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Numer == k.Numer).AdminName ?? String.Empty
            };
```

`AdminName` line is giving me the error, why can't it work like this?

I'm trying to get a value from `result` into `sheet` that matches by the `Numer`.

Comment: Admin != Administrator. Typo? By the way FirstOrDefault will presumably return null as default and accessing AdminName on that will result in an Exception.

Comment: What is `k`? You are using `a` twice: `from a in ...` and `FirstOrDefault(a => ...)` so you filter `result` by `k.Number` and use always the same AdminName for your db query. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: @Ralf `Admin` and `Administrator` are 2 separate objects. `Admin` is a bigger class with 20+ variables, `Administrator` is just to map data from SqlQuery.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Sorry, that was a typo, fixed now. `Admin` and `Administrator` both have `AdminName`. I'm trying to filter `result` by finding `a.Number` that is equal to `k.Number` and only take `.AdminName` property from `result`.

Comment: Please show how `result` is defined and how it gets filled.

Comment: @Ralf `var result = Context.Database.SqlQuery<Administrator>(raw sql here).ToList();`

Comment: Ok nothing in that area. Try adding a ToList() to AsNoTracking() here. I Assume EF tries to generate SQL for the result.FirstOrDefault call and can't obviously do that because result is something only in memory. The parts that create an Admin instance need to happen locally in memory.

Comment: @Ralf With ToList() added whole `new Admin(){
              // some other variables  
              Numer = k.Numer,           
              AdminName = result.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Numer == k.Numer).AdminName ?? String.Empty };` throws `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: Presumably what i mentioned in the first comment FirstOrDefault can return null. You maybe want to ask for `?.AdminName` to circumvent that.

Comment: @Ralf Unfortunately this does not fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the whole query is being sent to SQL Server, and when it gets to the bit where you try to create an `Admin` object, SQL Server goes "*Huh? What's one of those?*"

If you enumerate your query before that point, then the results are sent back from SQL Server to your code, where the `Admin` object can be created...

```cs
var sheet = Context.Admins.AsNoTracking()
            .ToList() 
            .Select(a => new Admin()
            {
              // some other variables  
              Numer = k.Numer,           
              AdminName = result.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Numer == k.Numer).AdminName ?? String.Empty
            });
```

I've converted your code to use method syntax, as I think it's easier to read for this sort of thing.

Either way, the point is to understand what bit of code gets executed where. Anything to do with your models must be executed in your code, not in the database, as that doesn't know about your models. The call to `ToList()` enumerates the query (ie actually runs it against the database). Everything after that then happens in your code.

As a side point, you should really be using async code for this sort of thing...

```cs
var sheet = (await Context.Admins.AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync())
            //... other code as before
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution throws `System.NullReferenceException` on the whole `.Select...`

Comment: That's now a different error. My guess is that your `FirstOrDefault` is returning null, and you haven't checked for that. You could try adding an `Include` to your query to make sure the extra data is being loading, and you should also check that it is actually present in the database